# Typecast function parameters

Tags: php, function, casting

I would like to check the type of a parameter matches, before I enter a the function.

```
function ((int) $integer, (string) $string ) { /*...*/ }
```

As opposed to

```
function ( $int, $string ) {
    $string = (string) $string;
    $int = (int) $int;
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I've also speculated in doing it as object

```
function ( Integer $int ) { /*...*/ }
```

By doing this I could send a `functionName ( new Integer ( $int ));` but I would love to not have the added syntax.

Comment: Unless its been added in 5.4 there is no type-hinting except on Classes/Interfaces and arrays.

Comment: Can you not simply use `is_*()` (i.e. `is_int()`, `is_string()`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You certainly can use so-called [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) with complex types (arrays, interfaces and objects) - but not with primitives (and, to my mild surprise, with traits as well):

> Type hints can not be used with scalar types such as int or string.
>   Traits are not allowed either.

While there's [a lot of proposals](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/typechecking) to add the scalar type hinting to PHP (there's even an informal [patch for that](http://ilia.ws/archives/217-Scalar-Type-Hints-are-Here!.html)), it's not that easy. I'd recommend checking out [this article](http://nikic.github.com/2012/03/06/Scalar-type-hinting-is-harder-than-you-think.html), as it sums up the potential pitfalls of different approaches pretty well.

P.S. BTW, it looks like PHP 5.5 [might use](http://nikic.github.com/2012/07/10/What-PHP-5-5-might-look-like.html#scalar_typehinting) that "check-and-cast" type hinting. Not to say I'm surprised...

Comment: Why was this down voted? I would love to know if he was down voted because of "faulty" info, or just because the person disagrees?

Comment: The same question from me, btw. )

Answer (score 19):

Starting in PHP 7 you can now use Scalar types (int, float, string, and bool) when type hinting.

```
function (int $int) { /*...*/ }
function (float $float) { /*...*/ }
function (string $string) { /*...*/ }
function (bool $bool) { /*...*/ }
```

As of OP's question, PHP only supported type hinting of objects, interfaces and the `array` type, but it is now possible to do what the question proposes natively.

Answer (score 0):

For **scalars** you can use the php **is_int()** .. **is_string()** functions to check.

For arrays and objects you can use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) in the function call.

There is a rumour that in the next version of php there will also type hinting support for scalars.

Comment: But I guess it won't work in the function: `function ( is_int ( $int ))`?

Comment: It will work, but not give you the expected integer, but a boolean as parameter.

Comment: @raina77ow Or you seem to be misunderstanding the question. I want it to fail if the type doesn't match. like it does for `function ( array $array ) {}`

Comment: @Kao I'm sorry, but from your statement it looked like you're more concerned about converting than checking the types. Of course, it's ok to use type hinting for checks; but it's not so simple with PHP (as I mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

There will be scalar type-cast-like type-hint in function parameters in php 5.5, but for now, only classes, `array` & `callable` only available (as of php 5.4)

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

You cant set such check for INT and STRING.

Comment: This link is about functions in OOP classes context. In procedural programming it became valid with PHP 7 only.

Comment: @CazumaNiiCavalcanti > answered Oct 22 '12 > 8 years later things change :) 
And yet I have wrote that he can't do it . So it was valid answer.